# Non pointer global variables in LLVM

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization

I'm writing a function pass, and would like to add a global variable of type int in the initialisation phase, for use in the actual work of the pass.

So far, I have

```
bool doInitialization(Module &M) {
    LLVMContext &c = M.getContext();
    Type *intTy = TypeBuilder<int,false>::get(c);
    Value *p = M.getOrInsertGlobal("var1",intTy);
    return true
}
```

For whatever reason, var1 has type int*. For example, adding this after the declaration

```
Type *pt = p->getType();
if (isa<PointerType>(pt)) {
    errs().write_escaped("Is a pointer ty") << '\n';
}
```

Will end up with a print when the compiled code is run, and

```
if ((intTy->getPointerTo()) == (p->getType())) {
  errs().write_escaped("This is confusing") << '\n';
}
```

Will again print the string.

Is it possible to add a global variable of type int using this method, and if so, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it right. Global variables are always stored in memory -- you've inserted a global variable of type `i32`, and gotten back a pointer to that memory location. In C terms, you got back `&var1` instead of `var1`. To manipulate the value stored in the pointer, you'll need to create `load` and `store` instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

This is slightly off topic, but I feel it's related enough to stay on this page:

In my function pass, I'm calling

Value* vpointer = M->getGlobalVariable("var1");
LoadInst load(vpointer,"var1",&i);

&i is from the iterator.

This code segfaults. The LoadInst is the problem, removing it removes the segfault. I think the issue is from the string argument to LoadInst(), because I'm basically just guessing what to put there (there's little documentation). How should I fix this segfault?

Comment: @LLVMHacker30 I'd suggest looking into using [`IRBuilder`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html) rather than creating instructions manually.

Comment: Not sure what this answer adds that my earlier answer didn't :(

Comment: @dune.rocks The upvote isn't mine (I don't have the 'reputation' to upvote) and I asked the followup to Ismail because he happened to be higher up the page when I came back. Both answers are really useful.

Answer (score 0):

When using `getOrInsertGlobal`, you pass the *underlying* type of the object you wish to create in the global namespace. The implementation then uses `getPointerType` to actually create the mapping in the module's symbol table, which is why you're seeing a pointer to the type you're passing in.

So you'll need to load and store to the global.